# Calculating the length of a Linked-List in Python

Tags: python, linked-list

I have a linked-list and I want to calculate it's length with a function, here's my definition :

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
```

Comment: Ok, where's your code that attempts to calculate the length?

Comment: Why not, in your linked-list class, have a variable that increments and decrements when you add or remove nodes to and from the list?

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt because you can't do that in any sensible way with a singly linked list.

Comment: I didn't know how to approach it, and I thought it's simple task to those who know, so it's okay to ask for the code without writing it.

Comment: @HiDay it's not.  SO is not a code-writing service, and questions like these are very likely to get closed.

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt Nice idea, but that doesn't cope if you perform more drastic manipulations on the linked list, eg truncating the list by setting the `.next` attribute of a middle node to `None`, or inserting one list into another list.

Comment: Note taken @thebjorn. Thanks for the help anyway, and will try next time :)

Comment: @thebjorn, I don't see why not.  In your `add_node` method, increment the variable.  In your `remove_node` method, decreemnt the variable.  I mean, sure, if OP is using this node class without a container class, then you wouldn't have a class var for length, but it's easier if OP has that second class.

Comment: @PM2Ring, fair point.  The context in which HiDay was planning to use his list would help to clarify what approach would best meet the requirements.

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt then it's no longer a singly linked list (SLL). With that implementation a concat/extend operation would have to be destructive (ie. two lists could no longer share nodes).

Comment: @HiDay This task isn't hard, but we still like to see your code. It shows us that you've put in some effort, and you don't just expect others to do your work for you. It also shows us that you want to learn, rather than to mindlessly copy code you don't understand. But besides all that, seeing your code makes it easier for us to understand exactly what your problem is, and what your knowledge / skill level is, which helps us write an answer targeted to your specific case that you'll be able to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function:

```
def length(lst):
    r = 0
    while lst:
        lst = lst.next
        r += 1
    return r # 'r' being the length
```

It works by moving forward along the list counting the number of nodes observed until a `None` link is encountered.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set the head node to a variable, and continuous count until you hit the point where `temp == NULL`

```
def height(list):
    temp=list.head
    count=0
    while temp:
        count+=1
        temp=temp.next
    return count
```